# How to plot int to datetime on x axis using seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use seaborn to plot a graph

```
sns.lmplot(x="when_start", y="how_long",hue= 'state',
           data=apps_pd.loc[(apps_pd['user'] == 'xavi')],lowess=True);
```

Where ***apps_pd*** is a dataframe. And fileds in ***apps_pd['when_start']*** are int like 1499963856220, and same for ***how_long***.

Result of the script

[image]

However, I got a really messy graph if I don't change the format of the data.

Is there anyway I could change the unit of x-axis to 'yyyy-mm-dd'? I want to group all my data in day level.

And also could I change the unit of y-axis to hour-min-second?

Here is the first 5 lines of my dataframe.
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details on your data. Your problem is fairly easy to fix by converting the variable to `datetime` format, e.g. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Hi @omdv which kind of detail do you need. I have try to use datetime. But I always get ***ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1*** error

Comment: The first ten lines of your dataframe should be enough, @Xavier.

Comment: Please provide the output of `apps_pd.head()`. Also when does it give you the ordinal error?

Comment: @omdv I have uploaded the dataframe

Comment: @Bonifacio2 just uploaded it

Answer (score 11):

First of all when you post data post it in text format not image.

You can convert col `when_start` to date time format as follow:

```
apps_pd['when_start'] = pd.to_datetime(apps_pd['when_start'], unit='ms')
```

However scatter plot which is one of calls of [lmplot does not support datetime](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/257) format. You have to replace your xtick marks after plotting like in this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

cols = ['how_long', 'state', 'user', 'when_start']
data = [[62297, 'FINISHED', 'xavi', 1499963793923],
 [25761, 'FINISHED', 'xavi', 1499963446385],
 [20082, 'FINISHED', 'xavi', 1499963221203],
 [20508, 'FINISHED', 'xavi', 1499963156760],
 [580975, 'FINISHED', 'xavi', 1499962435293]]

apps_pd = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
# convert ms timestamps of dataframe to date time format by pandas
#apps_pd['when_start'] = pd.to_datetime(apps_pd['when_start'], unit='ms')
print (apps_pd)

sns.lmplot(x='when_start', y='how_long', hue= 'state',
 data=apps_pd[(apps_pd['user'] == 'xavi')],lowess=True)

# get current axis
ax = plt.gca()
# get current xtick labels
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
# convert all xtick labels to selected format from ms timestamp
ax.set_xticklabels([pd.to_datetime(tm, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d\n %H:%M:%S') for tm in xticks],
 rotation=50)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Just wondering could I combine all the time on a daily basis? For this case, there is only one day on x axis which is 2017-07-13. And could I use the similar method to convert y axis to hour-minute?

Comment: I guess it is does not matter how many days you have, you may skip some labels if needed

Comment: what is `tm` in this example?

Comment: For me this was useful: 

ax.set_xticklabels([pd.to_datetime(int(tm)-737178, unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2019-04-28')).strftime('%b %Y') for tm in xticks], rotation=50)

Comment: @Sledge `tm` is part of the iterating reference in the list comprehension which in this case is each member of `xticks`. I suspect you missed it as I did whence I didn't scroll across.