# Python-My dataset contain datetime column and it doesnt allow me to make any process

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

As you see dataset below I have a datetime column and that couse some problem while I am trying to do coding

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
ad=pd.read_excel("DataSetTrain.xlsx")
df=ad.copy()
df["Tarih"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Tarih"])
df.head()
```

Trying to use

```
df.corr()
```

It just give me Total Call

When I try to do plotting

```
sns.pairplot(df, kind="reg")
```

It doesnt see row date. What should i do to fix that ? should i change the format of the datetime ?

Also when I try to use jointplot

```
sns.jointplot(x="Tarih",y="ToplamCagri",data=df, kind="reg")
```

It gives me

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Timestamp' and 'float'
```

| Row Date | Total Call |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 09:00:00.000 | 57 |
| 2021-09-01 09:15:00.000 | 52 |
| 2021-09-01 09:30:00.000 | 58 |

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `datetime.timestamp()` method as described in the second part [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime), as Pandas may be unable to use the datetime object as it is to do what you intend to do. This method will convert the datetime object to a Unix timestamp, which is "the number of seconds between a particular date and January 1, 1970 at UTC" as stated in the reference link.

There are a variety of options in this [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor) which you can use to convert the column.

Comment: I also try to manage problem with the unix timestamp. I coundt see the result that i expected.

Comment: Could you provide the error message for that as well?

Comment: Actually it is not a error. The x axis doesnt show the dates just show epoch time as a integer.

Comment: I see, hopefully at least the desired results have been generated. Now you need to make epoch time show up as a normal date on the Seaborn x-axis. This requires some conversion back to datetime. You can try the method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315084/17288157